# How to read value passed to the airflow backfill --conf {"key": "value"}

Tags: airflow

I have an airflow DAG which I can run with some parameters using:

```
airflow trigger_dag 'my_dag' --conf '{"key":"value"}'
```

then I can get the 'value' in my DAG like this:

```
context['dag_run'].conf.get('key')
```

I would like to do the same using backfill:

```
airflow backfill 'my_dag' --conf '{"key":"value"}' -s 2019-04-15 -e 2019-04-16
```

Is it possible to get passed value in --conf for backfill?

Answer (score 1):

I came upon this question while having the same issue, and although its a few years later I thought this might help someone.

As the OP suspected, prior DAG executions impact whether a backfill will use the conf provided in the command line. This was recently raised in [this issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/22336) and a fix merged: https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/22837

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the backfill command also has a `conf` parameter.

From: https://airflow.apache.org/1.10.3/cli.html#backfill

```
airflow backfill [-h] [-t TASK_REGEX] [-s START_DATE] [-e END_DATE] [-m] [-l]
                 [-x] [-i] [-I] [-sd SUBDIR] [--pool POOL]
                 [--delay_on_limit DELAY_ON_LIMIT] [-dr] [-v] [-c CONF]
                 [--reset_dagruns] [--rerun_failed_tasks] [-B]
                 dag_id

-c, --conf
JSON string that gets pickled into the DagRun’s conf attribute
```

Comment: maybe the issue is that I am trying backfill the DAG that has been run with the default parameters. I mean, when DAG was executed by airflow scheduler it didn't have any params. I cleared the instance, then executed command: airflow backfill -conf ... the str(context['dag_run'].conf) is None.  Why is that?